# How to ensure ruby gem install in a standalone script - 1st run fails, 2nd run works

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm new to this, and I'm obviously missing something...
I've searched, but haven't found something that matches this exactly.

**Running:**
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]

To ensure non-native gem install in standalone script

artii - https://github.com/miketierney/artii

```
def ensure_nn_gem(this_gem)
  begin
    gem this_gem
    rescue LoadError
      `gem install #{this_gem}`
    end
  require this_gem
end

ensure_nn_gem('artii')
```

**On first run**:

C:\Users****\Desktop********\lib>ruby my_app.rb

unable to convert "\xC4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/figlet/fonts/bubble.flf, skipping

unable to convert "\xC4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/figlet/fonts/digital.flf, skipping

unable to convert "\xB0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/figlet/fonts/l4me.flf, skipping

unable to convert "\x81" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/figlet/fonts/pyramid.flf, skipping

unable to convert "\xC4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/figlet/fonts/rot13.flf, skipping

unable to convert "\xC4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/figlet/fonts/term.flf, skipping

unable to convert "\xC4" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/figlet/fonts/tsalagi.flf, skipping

---

C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- artii (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'
        from app.rb:11:in `ensure_nn_gem'
        from app.rb:14:in`'

---

**On second run**:

The script works as intended.

Comment: The problem is that the Gem installs, but isn't seen in the list when require is encountered again.  It might have to do with rubygems alias of require... I'm not sure.  I think if there was a "refresh list", it would work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic- this gem loads after and stay in memory in case of `spring`.

try to add

`require 'artii'`

in the beginning of your code

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is trying to use the `gem this_name` syntax.
This is just for Gemfiles,
Stick to `require` in your scripts.